# Продолжить работу программы после выполнения условия

Tags: python, while

Как продолжить работу калькулятора после выполнения условия? Я только начал изучать python и не до конца понимаю работу `while True`.

```py
while True:

    a = float(input("Введите первое число:"))
    operator = input("Введите операцию:")
    b = float(input("Введите второе число:"))

    if operator == "+":
        c = a + b
        print(c)
        break
    if operator == "-":
        c = a - b
        print(c)
        break
    if operator == "*":
        c = a * b
        print(c)
        break
    if operator == "/":
        c = a / b
        print(c)
        break
    else:
        print("Неверная операция!")
    if input("Продолжим?(Y/N)") !="Y":
        break
```

Comment: А зачем вы везде `break` поставили? Уберите все, кроме последнего, если хотите, чтобы вопрос задавался после каждого вычисления. А все `if` кроме первого и последнего поменяйте на `elif`.

Comment: Спасибо большое, тупанул немного!

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал *CrazyElf* в комментариях, проблема была в лишних `break`. Решение будет выглядеть вот так:

```py
while True:
    a = float(input("Введите первое число:"))
    operator = input("Введите операцию:")
    b = float(input("Введите второе число:"))

    if operator == "+":
        c = a + b
        print(c)
    elif operator == "-":
        c = a - b
        print(c)
    elif operator == "*":
        c = a * b
        print(c)
    elif operator == "/":
        c = a / b
        print(c)
    else:
        print("Неверная операция!")

    if input("Продолжим?(Y/N)") != "Y":
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно заменить break на continue, это будет лучшим решением.

```
while True:

    a = float(input("Введите первое число:"))
    operator = input("Введите операцию:")
    b = float(input("Введите второе число:"))

    if operator == "+":
        c = a + b
        print(c)
        continue
    if operator == "-":
        c = a - b
        print(c)
        continue
    if operator == "*":
        c = a * b
        print(c)
        continue
    if operator == "/":
        c = a / b
        print(c)
        continue
    else:
        print("Неверная операция!")
    if input("Продолжим?(Y/N)") !="Y":
        break
```

Comment: Если требуется не спрашивать после распознанных операций, то проще `if` с вопросом сдвинуть в блок `else` и тогда `continue` не нужны опять же.